# Python List Change

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to convert an array containing arrays with items inside, to an array containing inverted... This is a bad example, so here is basically the concept of what I'm trying to do:

```
array1 = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]
array2 = doSomething(array1) # Do Something To The Array To Get Second:
# In The End I Want The Array To Be:
# array2 = [["1","4","A","D"],["2","5","B","E"],["3","6","C","F"]]
```

If that makes any sense...
Please let me know if you know a way that will allow you to do this if the number of arrays and items in each array is unknown (the number of items is the same for each array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
original_list = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['4', '5', '6'],
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'E', 'F']
    ]

new_list = list(zip(*original_list))

print(new_list)
```

Result:

```
[('1', '4', 'A', 'D'), ('2', '5', 'B', 'E'), ('3', '6', 'C', 'F')]
```